# Formatting text as code inside a numbered paragraph

Tags: support

In an answer, I use a numbered list and try to insert code. However, inside of the numbered passage, formatting as code does not work and I was not able either to paste the code to a next paragraph, outside of the numbered text block. See here for the problem: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/382253/88814

Is it possible somehow to format text inside of a numbered paragraph?

I used ` for the shorter expressions. However, when using it with the longer expression, it doesn't respect the line breaks at all (see second screenshot).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need more spaces (I've gone with 4 more) at the start of the code blocks.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you to use ```` ``` ````. In this case, no need a lot of spaces.

[image]