# Paste an image after codeblock

Tags: support

After successfully [formatting codeblocks after a numbered paragraph](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5242/formatting-text-as-code-inside-a-numbered-paragraph), I have a follow up question: How can I paste an image after the codeblock? This is the example: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/382627/88814

When I try to do so, I get this - several attempts to exit the codeblock were unsuccessfull. Unfortunately, I can't see any formatting options in the editor.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The start of your code block (the ```` ``` ````) was indented (to align it with the numbered list, I presume), so I guess the Markdown parser expects the end of the code block to be indented as well. I just tried that in a suggested edit on your answer, and at least from the preview it seems to work.